# Edubuntu LTSP client desktop management

Tags: ltsp

I am working with edubuntu to create a LTSP server.  I need to have control over the desktops of the client as this will be implemented in a school environment.  I have several LTSP 4 servers running on CentOS with KDE 3.5 using the kioskadmintool to manage the desktops.

Is there similar functionality with Edubuntu and LTSP 5?  Is is consolidated in a convenient tool or do I need several tools to manage it?

I do not need to stay with KDE.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install `italc` and then control the users 
desktop with it.

`sudo apt-get install libitalc italc-client italc-master`

Answer (score 0):

epoptes allows thin and fat client control, including WOL to power on the clients. It is included in the edubuntu install